# Найти место подключения/чтения файла в коде

Tags: json, база-данных, reactjs, веб-программирование, github

Скачал https://github.com/Archakov06/react-pizza. В этой папке есть файл /public/db.json с данными для карточек пицц. Подскажите в каком файле и на какой строчке происходит чтение данных из этого json файла.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

- Total Commander,
- Alt+f7 в папке или архиве,
- галочка "С текстом",
- вводите db.json,
- получаете два файла:

...

- react-pizza-master\package.json
- react-pizza-master\server.js

Найти в файле, думаю сможете сами. )

Comment: Хороший ответ на плохой вопрос!